# Add some options to profile page

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to add some options to profile page like this image, but I can't get the profile page slug:

[image]

Here my code:

```
/* Create settings section */
add_settings_section(
    'my-section-id',                   // Section ID
    'My Additional Profile Settings',  // Section title
    'my_settings_section_description', // Section callback function
    'profile'                          // Settings page slug
);
```

Comment: add_settings_section() function is for sections under settings menu, you can't use that function to add settings in profile page. Take a look at this example to achieve what you want: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields

Comment: u can also use advance custom field plugin do this https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I usually use this function add_settings_section() to add options to reading setting:
please check this link:
https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-add-settings-section-in-wordpress-default-settings/

Comment: take a look at this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214719/how-do-i-add-a-field-on-the-users-profile-for-example-country-age-etc

Comment: do you want to add profile page slug in setting reading page or profile page?

Comment: to profile page i'd like to understand not copy code and paste it :)